# What does it mean if I can't open an invite link by typing it into the browser?

Tags: instagram

Someone sent me an Instagram invite link that looks like this:

*https://instagram.com/invites/contact/?i=6t....&utm_content=t...*

the dots are the rest of the parts, but this is the structure. I didn't click on the link, but I took a screenshot of it. The link message is gone now, so I can't click, but I tried to type the full url link into my browser, and nothing happens. Only the homepage of Instagram keeps loading. What is that mean? Does it mean the link is invalid, or maybe it has expired?

Also, their username is something like this @first_second, but when I search for first_second in the Instagram search, I can only see an account with the username firstsecond without the underscore! Is that the same account or does it have to contain the underscore?